# Listing all types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, inheritance, linq-to-entities

I've defined a class "Contract", from which I derive several types of contracts.  I'm using Entity Framework for storage and opted for the Table-per-type model such that I end up with tables like Contract_Put, Contract_Call, for the different derived classes.

Now I want to list all contracts and create a field with strings identifying the contract type.  I tried something like this:

```
var ret = from c in db.Contracts select new ContractsVM { ... }
```

however, there's no way I can find to figure out the type of contract... help?

Comment: I'm confused, you say contract type and you want to display a field with a string identifying what type...but then you say you can't figure out what type of order. Could you clarify?

Comment: @doreye01, sorry about that.  I've edited it so it makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var ret = from c 
              in db.Contracts.OfType<Contract_Put> 
              select new ContractsVM { strType="Put",... };
ret = ret.Concat(from c 
              in db.Contracts.OfType<Contract_Call> 
              select new ContractsVM { strType="Call",... });
```

The variable `ret` contains all these values. Hope it helps!

Comment: ah.  I was afraid that was going to be it.  I hoped for a way to pick up the type from the Contracts but I guess that's not reasonable.  thanks.